# Get LAST_INSERT_ID in this bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a script executing MySQL queries (see below). If it's a INSERT query, I want to return the LAST_INSERT_ID(),

```
mysql_exec_result=$(
    printf "%s\n" \
      "[client]" \
      "user=${CONFIG_DB_USERNAME}" \
      "password=${CONFIG_DB_PASSWORD}" \
      "host=${CONFIG_DB_HOST}" \
      "port=${CONFIG_DB_PORT}" \
      "database=${CONFIG_DB_DATABASE}" \
      | HOME="/sys" mysql --defaults-file=/dev/stdin ${opts} -e "${query}"
  )
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Have you tried using something like `SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1;`?

Comment: And also each language is different but usually sql connections keep track of last insert id. For PHP would be `$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are executing the query from outside of MySQL, you are open to use bash commands to execute further commands dependent on the first.

You can store your query in a variable, and then run an if statement like the below example:

```
query="INSERT.....";
if [[ $query == *"INSERT"* ]]; 
then 
mysql -e "$query; SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();"
else
mysql -e "$query"
fi
```

In the above, if the query that you are executing contains any INSERT command, then it will get you the LAST_INSERT_ID after the INSERT is ran.

If the query does not contain an INSERT, then it will action the query without getting the LAST_INSERT_ID following query completion.

The "mysql -e" command can be amended to include your required flags accordingly.

The if statement example provided, can be put on a one line as per the below:

```
query="INSERT....."; if [[ $query == *"INSERT"* ]]; then mysql -e "$query; SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();"; else mysql -e "$query"; fi
```

Comment: The 'last_insert_id()' is only  valid in the same session of the insert. Otherwise, there is a chance that there will be additional inserts, and the code will get the wrong 'last_id',

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I have edited my answer accordingly so that the LAST_INSERT_ID select is actioned at the same time as the query with "mysql -e "$query; SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();""

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to extend and complete binbashbosh's answer here for the following reasons:

1. It is clear from the code whether it is an insert statement or not. Therefore, a query for the keyword INSERT seems unnecessary or even dangerous: `INSERT INTO TableName VALUES (ColName) ('ShoppingCartINSERT');`  would meet the if condition, too.
2. It is necessary to assign the ID of the inserted record to a variable in order to be able to process it further. `tail -1` gets the last line of the valued returned, which is the newly inserted id.
3. It is useful to provide the sql credentials with the statement.
4. Finally, it is necessary to check for errors, that is, if the returned ID isn't a positive integer.

```bash
# define constants
readonly DB_USER="myUser"
readonly DB_PASSWD="myPwd"
readonly DB_NAME="myDB"

# define query
query="INSERT.....";
# execute query and add result
myID=$(mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME -e "$query; SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();" | tail -1)

# check if myID is a positive integer
regExPosInt='^[1-9][0-9]*$'
if ! [[ $myID =~ $regExPosInt ]] ; then
   echo "Error: ..." >&2; exit 1
fi
echo myID
```